# How to Organize a Messy Database

Tags: sql-server, relational-database, data-modeling, data-warehouse

I know there is no easy answer to this question, but how do I cleanup a database with no relationships, foreign keys, and not a whole lot of structure?

I'm an amateur to SQL, and I've inherited a database that is complete mess. We have no sort of referential integrity, and there's not a whole lot of logic to how tables are working.

My database is all data that comes from a warehouse that builds servers.
To give you an idea of the type of data I'm working with:

- EDI from customers
- Raw output from server projects
- Sales information
- Site information
- Parts lists

I have been prioritizing Raw output and EDI information, and generating reports with that information using SSRS. I have learned a lot about SQL Server and the BI Microsoft tools (SSIS and SSRS) in my short time doing this. However, I'm still an amateur and I want to build a solid database that flows well and can stand on its own.

It seems like a data warehouse model is the type of structure I should adapt.
My question how do I take my mess of a database and make something more organized before I drown in data?

Comment: I can give you a quick tip and tell you to try to ensure that each table has a primary key, which will make them have an index.  Indexing will help ensure faster queries.  A good read, straight from MS, is [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described).

Comment: The one thing we do have are primary keys! Sometimes more than one. Indexing was something I planned to implement for some of our larger tables.

Comment: @AlanPear, it's not necessarily fatal to have no *enforced* constraints - I've seen them removed for performance and administrative reasons. I'd be looking more deeply about whether the design itself is sound, if it seems to be a "mess". It's surprising how often one encounters accounting and stock-keeping systems designed by people with not even basic knowledge of those areas. I'd think twice about doing any sudden total overhaul, and bear in mind that any change to the basic structure already in place will require everything that is currently built on top of it to be reviewed and reworked.

Comment: That does give some peace of mind. Thank you for the comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your end goal appears to be business reporting, and you're dealing with data from multiple sources made up from "isolated" tables, I would advise you to start by aggregating all that into a data model.

Personally, I would design a dimensional model to structure and store all that data, with the goal of being easy to understand (for reporting or adhoc querying). The model should be focused on business entities and their transactions. In a dimensional model, the business entities will (almost always) be the dimensions and the transactions (the metrics) will be the facts. For example, without knowing your model I'm guessing that the immediate entities would include Customer, Site, Part and transactions would include ServerSale, SiteVisit, PartPurchase, PartRepair, PartOrder, etc...

More information about dimensional modelling [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_modeling) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema), but I suggest going straight to the source: https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/books/data-warehouse-dw-toolkit/

When your model is designed (and implemented in a database like SQL Server) you'll then be loading data into the model, by extracting it from its different source systems/databases and transforming it from the current structure into the structure defined by the model, namely by using an [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) tool like MS Integration Services. For example, your Customer data may be scattered across the "sales", "customer" and "site", so you want to aggregate all that data and load it into a single Customer dimension table. It's when doing this ETL that you should check your data for the problems you already mentioned, loading correct rows into you data model and discarding incorrect rows into a file/log where they can later be checked and corrected. (multiple ways to address this).

A straightforward tutorial to get started on doing ETL using SSIS can be found at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj720568(v=sql.110).aspx

So, to sum up, you should build a [data mart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mart):

1. design a dimensional model that represents the business facts and
   context on the data you have. This will strongly facilitate both data understanding and reporting, because a dimensional model is closely matches business users terminology and mental models.
2. use an ETL tool to extract the data from its current source, process it (e.g. check for data quality problems, join data from different sources) and load it into the dimensional model and check it for problems. This will get you close to having an automated data integration job/pipeline with quality checks you deem fit for the data.